# Consume REST API sequentially, with at least 100 milisecs between each call in a multi-threaded env. (w/ RestTemplate)

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, thread-safety, resttemplate

I have a highly concurrent environment consuming a REST web service. The REST service documentation says that each call to the API should be made with at least with 100 miliseconds between each call (10 calls per second). Also, the REST API does not support concurrent calls. They should be made one by one, waiting the response before trigger another request. The approach I came with is:

```
private static RestTemplate restTemplate; // Rest template configured and working.

public ResponseEntity<T> consume() {
    ...
    try {
        synchronized (restTemplate) { // Locking on static RestTemplate.
            response = restTemplate.exchange(endpointUrl, httpMethod, request, classType, uriData);

            try {
                restTemplate.wait(100); // Is this OK?
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return response;
    } catch (final HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e);
    }
}
```

Is it correct? Thank you!

Comment: You might be interested in the resilience4j Bulkhead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot based on what you want to achieve. The code you posted is most probably incomplete so is hard to give an exact solution. Also, it does the same request
    and my guess is that it should be something different each time  (uriData or request).

How many calls do you have to make? If the answer is a fixed number most probably an `for` with a `Thread.sleep(100);` might be good enought. Otherwise, if you are having  diferents events that are triggering a call to this service and the parameters are different I would have a blocking queue and a thread that would consume and sleep for 100 ms. The producers will add to the queue and there will be a consumer that will just make a call at 100 ms interval if there is something in the queue, otherwise, it will just wait.